# Conditional Formatting of Gridview Not Working After Row Selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview that conditionally get formatted based on a cell value. It works great when the page loads, however when I select a row it formats it for the first given condition (black) for all of the rows. Here is the code for the conditional formatting.

```
 //Conditionally formats the gridview to show banner colors
protected void EmployeeAchievementsGV_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //Black Banner
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        int CellValue = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "TotalAchievementsEarned"));
        if (CellValue >= 0 && CellValue < 12)
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.Black;
            e.Row.Cells[0].ForeColor = Color.White;
            e.Row.Cells[1].ForeColor = Color.White;
            e.Row.Cells[2].ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
    }

    //Yellow Banner
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int CellValue = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "TotalAchievementsEarned"));
        if (CellValue >= 12 && CellValue < 24)
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            e.Row.Cells[0].ForeColor = Color.Black;
            e.Row.Cells[1].ForeColor = Color.Black;
            e.Row.Cells[2].ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }

    //Blue Banner
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int CellValue = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "TotalAchievementsEarned"));
        if (CellValue >= 24 && CellValue < 36)
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
            e.Row.Cells[0].ForeColor = Color.White;
            e.Row.Cells[1].ForeColor = Color.White;
            e.Row.Cells[2].ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
    }

    //Orange Banner
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int CellValue = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "TotalAchievementsEarned"));
        if (CellValue >= 36 && CellValue < 48)
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.Orange;
            e.Row.Cells[0].ForeColor = Color.Black;
            e.Row.Cells[1].ForeColor = Color.Black;
            e.Row.Cells[2].ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }

    //Pink Banner
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int CellValue = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "TotalAchievementsEarned"));
        if (CellValue >= 48)
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.HotPink;
            e.Row.Cells[0].ForeColor = Color.Black;
            e.Row.Cells[1].ForeColor = Color.Black;
            e.Row.Cells[2].ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on what might be causing the issue or how to resolve the issue would be great.

Comment: Which method are you using? DataBound? DataBind? RowCreating? Could could you post this?

Comment: also - assuming you have row selection enabled, a selected row has it's own set of formatting that need to be overridden - you need to enact that same conditional formatting in a row selection event

Comment: It is the RowCreated method.

Comment: if your formatting based on cell content, you are better off using the RowDataBound event as data will already be there and you can simply check the cell contents.  Doing this in the created event adds an extra binding call as it's going to happen again in the RowDataBound event anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the method from RowCreated to RowDataBound as @fnostro suggested and it works perfectly!